# JavaScript toLocaleString returning incorrect value for Africa/Cairo time zone on Microsoft's Edge

Tags: javascript, timezone, microsoft-edge, dst

It's been more than a week since Egypt re-introduced DST but following JS statement still returns incorrect value on Edge.  (Chrome never have the problem.)

```
new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'Africa/Cairo' }))
```

Is this something that can be fixed by a setting in Windows?

[Screenshot of console runs on Edge vs Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxyPu.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Microsoft Edge that the "Eastern European Summer Time" is not recognized in Edge for Cairo-timezone. This needs further investigation.

Current workaround is to change your Windows timezone to "(UTC + 02:00) Beirut" (or other UTC + 02:00 region), as Edge applies there Eastern European ​Summer Time correctly. As to `toLocaleString`, you need to change 'Africa/Cairo' into 'Asia/Beirut' (or other UTC + 02:00 region).

**UPDATE**

Microsoft has resolved this issue in Microsoft Edge Stable version 113.0.1774.45 (yet to release). On Microsoft Edge Canary (115.0.1846.0, has been released), this issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just amazed how this is a "known issue" and somehow it's tolerated as it still exists.

Comment: @S-A You're welcome. Actually, it is not tolerated because the Dev Team is investigating it. Hopefully a fix will be delivered in the next few updates.

Comment: @S-A A fix is on the way to Microsoft Edge. Please check my updated answer.